# Will image load faster if I use native app instead of webview app?

Tags: android, angular, react-native

If I have image gallery section on my app (like instagram or facebook photo gallery), will it load faster from user perspective if I use native instead of  web view? Or since the image is still need to be loaded from server, the loading time will still be the same?

Comment: Yes of course. When you use Webview you only not download the images but also those html text, js, css etc. whereas if you have a native app the layout is ready and it only needs to download the images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The native approach will take less resource. But for performance webview may not be considered slow. For network calls you have to pass all data to webview and can do the same with same or less effort by implementing API like volly or picasso to an ImageView.

Also for webview running on lower end devices have to do more work and make it appear less attractive for bigger applications compared to native approach.